# Intellij Idea Maven Project Compiler Output Is Alway Changed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

> Intellij Idea Project Settings 
> Compiler Output
>
> - Inherit project compile output path
> - Use module compile output path

I choose `Use module compile output path` option，but it is alway changed in another path, not my project compile output path. I can not run my project in correct.

Any help?

Output Path: `D:\repo\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\2.5.12\target\classes`

Test output path: `D:\repo\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\2.5.12\target\test-classes`

Comment: IDE uses Maven configuration as an initial source of project configuration. So, manual changed in project configuration will be overridden on Maven reload. Is it possible to share project to check where path comes from?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by setting `relativePath` in pom.xml.

By the way, the official description of `relativePath` is:

> The relative path of the parent pom.xml file within the check out. If
> not specified, it defaults to ../pom.xml. Maven looks for the parent
> POM first in this location on the filesystem, then the local
> repository, and lastly in the remote repo. relativePath allows you to
> select a different location, for example when your structure is flat,
> or deeper without an intermediate parent POM. However, the group ID,
> artifact ID and version are still required, and must match the file in
> the location given or it will revert to the repository for the POM.
> This feature is only for enhancing the development in a local checkout
> of that project. Set the value to an empty string in case you want to
> disable the feature and always resolve the parent POM from the
> repositories.